# Handle loading of scripts in a page for different devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I have a JS script to be included in a page for different devices such as Desktop, Tablets & Phones.
The script is something like :

```
For Desktops :<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.asp?id=495"></script>
For Tablets : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.asp?id=496"></script>
For Smartphones : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.asp?id=497"></script>
```

Essentially all that is necessary is a change to the query string dependent upon media query.

Which will be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're ok working around its [limitations](http://caniuse.com/matchmedia), matchmedia is probably the way to go.  http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/